# Pandas Series aggregating by time results in duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm fighting with a pandas problem I just don't get my head around.
So I have a `datetime` indexed pandas Series `my_series`:

```
Time
2017-04-25 15:10:44     8
2017-04-25 15:17:20    27
2017-04-25 16:23:51    31
2017-04-25 17:49:47    15
2017-04-25 17:53:00     4
2017-04-25 17:55:15     3
2017-04-25 18:53:37     7
2017-04-25 18:54:00     4
2017-04-25 19:00:36     5
2017-04-25 22:34:19    18
2017-04-25 23:08:52     6
2017-04-26 07:47:46    10
2017-04-26 07:59:54     9
2017-04-26 08:05:18     8
2017-04-26 08:12:40     8
2017-04-26 09:24:30    19
2017-04-26 09:49:12     5
2017-04-26 09:52:26     5
2017-04-26 11:35:09     4
2017-04-26 12:34:00     8
..
Name: Duration, dtype: int64
```

Now I try to group this data on a weekly basis:

```
my_series.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("W")).apply(print)
```

or

```
my_series.resample("W").apply(print)
```

Where both ways lead to the same result:

```
Time
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
2017-04-25 15:10:44    8
                      ..
```

So for some reason it duplicates the values like crazy. Can someone explain to me why it behaves like that and how I could change that to what I would expect, namely that I receive the actual array consisting of the data of a certain week.

Comment: I could not replicate your problem with pandas 0.21.0.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks for trying, I'm using 0.22.0 and tried multiple times with different datasets but as I said I have no clue why it does what it does

Comment: Is your index a `DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: @ytu I think so yes, at least I created it from `datetime.datetime` objects.